# Generating alternating current using capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance

I'm working on a device to use the electrostatic electricity to generate electricity. I have read that the electric field is far more powerful than  a magnetic field but less in recent years have people innovated in the area of static electricity.

I need someone who can help with what I have  discovered. if you get a capacitor that is two plates and a dielectric  and next to it you put two plates close but not in contact at opposite sides and the capacitor in the middle is charged, each of its plates will act as a layden jar to induce charges in the outside plates. when the outside plates are connected it will induce current because a huge potential difference is created between the outside plates.

If i fixed the two outside plates in one place and rotated the capacitor at 60hz so that the electric field is charging fast just like a magnetic generator,

will it produce constant current if the capacitor itself is not discharged?
[image]

[image]

Comment: The electric field outside a normally charged capacitor is zero except at the edges due to fringe effect, because the net charge on the capacitor is zero and per Gauss' law th electric field outside is zero. The figure you provided is probably for the top plate being given a positive charge in the absence of the bottom plate, and then causing the mobile electrons in the bottom plate to move to the surface facing the top when brought close to the top leaving the opposite surface positively charged. But unlike a normally charged capacitor, the net charge on the bottom plate is zero an not $-Q$.

Comment: @Bob D checkout the new explanation

Comment: @Mark Eichenlaub request your view on this